# Is there any vulnerability if I hmac(key,key)?

Tags: hmac

It is a general question, but I'm using SHA-2.

My reason is to take a short pin or string and to generate a longer hash of that pin to locally generate a local key for personal use to be used to generate other passwords based on a domain and user name.

Eg.

```
Site password = Hmac( Hmac(pin,pin), Domain + username)
```

Or

```
Site password = Hmac( Hmac(pin,pin), hmac(Domain + username))
```

Additional info: Random passwords, unique for each account is ideal. But then I need to trust a password manager and install it on every device I own or use - this seems worse as I already trust Chromium/Google to store my passwords - why introduce another party? - and it seems popular password managers are patching design and implementation flaws a few times a year (and my code is no different).

My aim is to make any released passwords or hashes so long and pattern-free that my hashed passwords would remain un-cracked. And if cracked, then only one account would be compromised.

This is the idea I'm working on, it is not my idea, just my implementation.

In doing so I wondered if hmac(key,key) leaked info about the key or perhaps was trivial to crack. So after finding nothing on first page of a google search I decided to ask the SE community.

Comment: Why use a hmac? Why not a secure hash function directly, or better yet a KDF like PBKDF2 or Argon2 or Scrypt.

Comment: Ignorance is my excuse. Pbkdf2 requires a salt. I assume I can pick any random number but then I would need to remember it as well as pin. Seems like I'd need  to pbkdf2(sha512hmac,key,key,1000,64) which seems similar to my question. I'll look at Argon2 and scrypt... Ta.

Comment: You really should use a password manager and randomly generate passwords. This way a compromised password will not leak information on the others.

Comment: I don't trust password managers and I shouldn't trust Google but I do for now. Google Chrome seems to be moving towards being a password manager and generator (it offered to generate a password for me once so far) but I'm looking to learn and play around with something for myself.

Answer (score 3):

This is all useless.

The point of hashing passwords is to prevent a hacker who obtained the database with the hash to retrieve the original password.

With a short pin (assuming 4 digits) a hacker will simply calculate your hmac for all 10000 possible codes. None of your variations will make any significant difference.
A secure hash will hardly help either.

Comment: Yes I know this. I'm not concerned about this scenario although I'd be unlikely to use a 4 digit pin - sorry for misleading you. In any case, if someone gets my PC then I suspect they will be able to get all my passwords directly from Chromium.